# Editing Chrome's AutoplayAllowlist

Tags: google-chrome, autoplay

We're building a web app for our business that is specifically designed to make audible alarms when things go bad, but it seems we're blocked by Chrome's autoplay policy.
We *can* get around this by checking on load whether the `AudioContext` state is `suspended` and then show a dialog box to accept sound, which then runs the `resume()` method on the audiocontext, but it seems stupid that every time someone logs in it first asks them to allow sound for an app whose sole purpose is to audibly alert the client to a problem.

I did read [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) that you can override this behaviour for specific urls by changing the [AutoplayAllowlist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=AutoplayAllowlist)... but there seem to be no instructions on how to do this at all. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround was just to try play() and catch the error to then request the user allow sound and offer browser specific instructions on how to change the site settings to always allow sound.